# not run sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

after run `sudo apt upgrade` in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS show error :

```
~# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kwayland-data libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-iostreams1.62.0
  libboost-serialization1.62.0 libboost-system1.62.0 libcapnp-0.5.3
  libcapnp-0.6.1 libdfu1 libfam0 libfwupd1 libhfstospell9 libkf5archive5
  libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5 libkf5bookmarks-data
  libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5
  libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5
  libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5
  libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5
  libkf5doctools5 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5guiaddons5
  libkf5i18n-data libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews-data
  libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5
  libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5mediaplayer-data
  libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifications5 libkf5parts-data
  libkf5service-data libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data
  libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5wallet-data
  libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5widgetsaddons5
  libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui-data
  liblttng-ust-ctl4 liblttng-ust0 libmirclient9 libmircommon7 libmircore1
  libmirprotobuf3 libphonon4qt5-4 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libprocess-cpp3
  libprotobuf-lite10 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5test5 libqt5xml5 libtgvoip1.0
  libunity-api0 liburcu6 libvoikko1 libzmqpp4 phonon4qt5
  phonon4qt5-backend-vlc sonnet-plugins ubuntu-app-launch
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/153 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: error processing package fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fonts-tlwg-sawasdee:
 fonts-tlwg-sawasdee depends on fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf | fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-otf; however:
  Package fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf is not configured yet.
  Package fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-otf is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package fonts-tlwg-sawasdee (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf
 fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

solve problem with :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf
```